# Query rows by time of creation?

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I have a table that contains no date or time related fields. Still I want to query that table based on when records/rows were created. Is there a way to do this in PostgreSQL?

I prefer an answer about doing it in PostgreSQL directly. But if that's not possible, can hibernate do it for PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 6):

Basically: **no**. There is no automatic timestamp for rows in PostgreSQL.

I usually add a column like this to my tables (ignoring time zones):

```
ALTER TABLE tbl ADD COLUMN log_in timestamp DEFAULT localtimestamp NOT NULL;
```

As long as you don't manipulate the values in that column, you got your creation timestamp. You can add a trigger and / or restrict write privileges to avoid tempering with the values.

#### Second class options

- If you have a serial column, you could at least tell with *some* probability in what order  rows were entered. That's not 100% reliable, because the values can be changed by hand, and applications can get values from the sequence and `INSERT` out of order.
- If you created your table [`WITH (OIDS=TRUE)`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html), then the OID column could be some indication - unless your database is heavily written and / or very old, then you may have gone through OID wrap-around and later rows can have a smaller OID. That's one of the reasons, why this feature is hardly used any more.

  The default depends on the setting of [`default_with_oids`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-compatible.html#GUC-DEFAULT-WITH-OIDS) I quote the manual:

> The parameter is off by default; in PostgreSQL 8.0 and earlier, it was
>   on by default.

- If you have not updated your rows or went through a dump / restore cycle, or ran `VACUUM FULL` or `CLUSTER` or  .. , a plain `SELECT * FROM tbl` returns all rows in the order they were entered. But this is very unreliable and implementation-dependent. PostgreSQL (like any RDBMS) does not guarantee any order without an `ORDER BY` clause.